# Unable to export functions from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc

I need to create a C++ MFC DLL using Visual Studio 2008. To do this I created a DLL MFC Win32 Console project in Visual Studio and made a function that creates an object and uses its method to print a string to the screen. Kind of like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Foo(void);
```

where:

```
    void Foo(void){
    print* obj = new print;
    obj->testPrint();
    return;
}

void print::testPrint(void){
    printf("Bar\n");
    return;
}
```

It compiles successfully and generates the DLL, but when I try to use it I always get:
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Foo(void)"

I tried using Dependency Walker and it doesn't show any function up in the DLL. Am I doing something wrong? I've searched a lot and still got no conclusions from what may be happening.

Comment: Are you linking your application with the import library created with your dll?

Comment: Yes, I think the linking is ok. My guess is that maybe the DLL is coming out corrupted or something. Dependency Walker can't even find anything in it.

Comment: You do not link to .dlls so this can not be the problem.

Comment: Does your console application have a prototype for Foo like this: __declspec(dllimport) void Foo(void);

Comment: Remember you use __declspec(dllexport) in the dll itself and use __declspec(dllimport) for any application that uses the dll.

Comment: I created a new project and it worked. I really can't figure why this happened. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may not have included the header file which specifies the export in any cpp file. Remember that the cpp files are the only ones actually compiled. So make sure you include the header with the `__declspec(dllexport) void Foo(void);` in at least one cpp file. Also make sure that your project Linker->Input settings don't have a 'Module Definition File' (def) file specified.

Don't bother trying to link to the DLL until dependency walker shows that something is actually exported.

Comment: That was the issue!! I did not have the header file included in any .cpp file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Windows defaults to cdecl so you need to make explicit that it's exported declspec in the caller - or export it from the DLL as cdecl instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **export** the symbol explicitly from CPP file also:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void Foo(void)
{ 
    print* obj = new print; 
    obj->testPrint(); 
    return; 
}
```

The specification in header is merely for the client (EXE), and a hint for the linker from the server (DLL).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not quite right. The definitions don't need the export declaration but they must match everything else, e.g. calling conventions etc.

Comment: Yes, that's true - declaration must match. But I have seen linker not been able to export/resolve the symbol, unless explictly exported from implementation file.

Comment: We've never put the export declaration on the definition in the cpp file. We only include that information in the .h file that (depending on how it's included) will either dllimport or dllexport. It's not a massive issue but anything that adds to maintenance overhead should be avoided.